# product of the numbers in list in java

Tags: java, arraylist, java-collections-api

My task here is to find the minimal positive integer number say 'A' so that the product of digits of 'A' is exactly equal to N.

example: lets say my N = 32
so my A would be 48 coz the divisors of 32 would be 1,2,4,8,16,32 and the minimum numbers that would make 32 is 4 and 8. so output is 48.

what i did is first read N, then found the divisors and stored them in a list. and used

`if(l.get(i)*l.get(i+1)==N) {
sysout.print(l.get(i));
sysout.print(l.get(i+1));`

but im not able to make the numbers as minimum. and also i need to print as -1 if no match is found.

for that i did:

```
if (l.get(i)*l.get(i+1)!=N) {
              System.out.print(-1);
break;
          }
```

but it is printing -1 initially only and breaking off. now im stuck here. please find my code below:

my code:

```
int N=1;
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      System.out.println("Enter N: ");
      if (N>=0 && N<=Math.pow(10, 9)) {
          N = in.nextInt();  
      }

      for (int i=1; i<=N;i++) {
          if (N%i==0) {
              l.add(i);
          }
      }
       System.out.println(l);
      for (int i=0; i<l.size()-1;i++) {
          if (l.get(i)*l.get(i+1)==N) {
              System.out.print(l.get(i));
              System.out.print(l.get(i+1));
          }

      }

     in.close();
```

kindly help. thanks.

Comment: Your are looking for the minimum _number_, not the minimum pair of divisors! So for example if N=18, divisors are 1,2,3,6,9,18 and A=29 since 2*9=18. Note that 2 and 9 are not adjacent numbers in the list of divisors. So you cannot simply use indexes i and i+1.

Comment: Also when building the list of divisors you can ignore values >= 10 because a single digit is in the range 0..9. 0 and 1 are also of no interest because 0*n=0 and 1*n=n.

Comment: thank you for correcting me.. i cannot use i and i+1 as they are not adjacent numbers. i was wrong. should think of an other method to solve this.

Comment: I assume duplicate digits would be allowed, right? As in N=25, A=55? And what about more than two digits, for example N=105, A=357?

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor Since you're adding this specific tag to a lot of questions in the last days, can you explain why this question needs that tag? How is this relevant in solving this question?

Comment: yes @devconsole, for N = 105, A=357. that is correct. it is possible

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with finding the divisors on N. I'm not going to code it for you(you'll learn more by doing) but here's what you do: The divisors will be sorted already so loop the arraylist adding first to last and finding the min.
So for 1,2,4,8,16,32: Find 1+32, 2+16, 4+8; And then fin the max among these.

This is to get you started:

```
int first = 0;
int last = l.size()-1;

while(first<last){
 //Find min using Math.min;
 ++first;
 --last;
}
```

Happy Coding!

Could not resist. Below is a quick way to do what you want. Tested it here
(https://ideone.com/E0f4X9):

```
public class Test {
static ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    int N =32;
    findDivisors(N);

    int first = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
    int last = nums.size()-1;

    int results = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    while(first < last){
        int sum = nums.get(first) + nums.get(last);
        results = Math.min(sum,results);
        a = nums.get(first);
        b = nums.get(last);
        first++;
        last--;
    }

    System.out.println(a+" "+b);
}

private static void findDivisors(int n){

    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        if(n%i == 0){
            nums.add(i);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: what i actually want to do is to find the minimum numbers when multiplied give N.

Comment: I'll appreciate a vote on my answer.The minimum numbers are a and b. All you have to do is: System.out.println(a+" "+b);

Comment: the above code aint working and actually didnt understand your code.

Comment: Do some work yourself and don't expect people to be doing your work for you! Look here for the code: https://ideone.com/E0f4X9

Comment: in order to understand the code, you need to run it once to check whether its working or not.. only then u can go step by step to understand. you read a wrong code, dont understand what is inside, struggle.. no point right.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if N<10 then A=N.

Otherwise A has to consist of more than one digit. Every digit of A is a divisor of N. The more significant digits of A always have to be less or equal than the lesser significant digits. Otherwise the order of digits could be changed to produce a smaller number.

For example A could not be 523 because the digits could be rearranged into 235 which is a smaller number. In this example we have 2 < 3 < 5.

Observation #1: when looking at A the smallest digits are at the front, the digits get higher towards the end.

Observation #2, A can never contain two digits *a* and *b* if the product of *a* and *b* is also a digit. For example, there can never be a 2 and a 3, there would have to be a 6 instead. There could never be three 2s, it would have to be an 8 instead.

This suggests that when building A we should start with the highest possible divisors of N (because a 9 is always better than two 3s, and so on). Then we should put that digit at the end of A.

So, while N > 10, find the highest divisor *x* of N that is a single digit (2<=*x*<=9). Add this value *x* to the end of A. Divide N by *x* and proceed with the loop.

**Example:**

N=126, A=?

Highest possible divisor *x* that is less or equal to 9 is **9**. So 9 is going to be the last digit of A.

Divide N by 9 and repeat the process. N=126/9=14.

Now N=14, A=?9

Highest possible divisor *x* that is less or equal to 9 is **7**. We have found the second to last digit of A.

Divide N by 7 and repeat the process. N=14/7=2.

Now N=2, A=?79

N<10. So **2** is the first digit of A.

The solution is A=279

Comment: highest possible divisors of N are better, but for this question we need to find the minimum possible integers

Comment: Actually it is me who pointed that out to you. I'm editing my answer to give you an example.